# How do I implement play/pause buttons on an audioSourceNode in javascript?

Tags: javascript, audio

I'm having trouble implementing simple play and pause buttons on this SourceNode using JavaScript.

This is my audioManipulater.js file, everything gets viewed on index.php and styled on style.css.

So back to my js file. If you look at the _visualize method on the 1st line of the source. In the method the `audioBufferSourceNode` holds the file that has been loaded.

On line 13 the `start()` and `stop()` methods are being used on the audio node. How can I get a reference to the `audioBufferSourceNode` out of the library so that I can call these methods to play and pause the sound somehow?.

```
 _visualize: function(audioContext, buffer) {
    var audioBufferSourceNode = audioContext.createBufferSource(),
        analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser(),
        that = this;
    //connect the source to the analyser
    audioBufferSourceNode.connect(analyser);
    //connect the analyser to the destination(the speaker), or we won't hear the sound
    analyser.connect(audioContext.destination);
    //then assign the buffer to the buffer source node
    audioBufferSourceNode.buffer = buffer;
    //play the source
    if (!audioBufferSourceNode.start) {
        audioBufferSourceNode.start = audioBufferSourceNode.noteOn //in old browsers use noteOn method
        audioBufferSourceNode.stop = audioBufferSourceNode.noteOff //in old browsers use noteOn method
    };
    //stop the previous sound if any
    if (this.animationId !== null) {
        cancelAnimationFrame(this.animationId);
    }
    if (this.source !== null) {
        this.source.stop(0);
    }
    audioBufferSourceNode.start(0);
    this.status = 1;
    this.source = audioBufferSourceNode;
    audioBufferSourceNode.onended = function() {
        that._audioEnd(that);
    };
    this._updateInfo('Playing ' + this.fileName, false);
    this.info = 'Playing ' + this.fileName;
    document.getElementById('fileWrapper').style.opacity = 0.2;
    this._drawSpectrum(analyser);
 },
```

I'll edit-in my code for index.php & style.css upon request if needed.

EDIT
full code:

https://jsfiddle.net/4hty6kak/1/

For some reason the visualizer doesn't work on jsfiddle, so here is a link to a live working demo:

http://wayou.github.io/HTML5_Audio_Visualizer/

Comment: You say "In the method the audioBufferSourceNode holds the file that has been loaded," but in your code, you initialize `audioBufferSourceNode` with `audioBufferSourceNode = audioContext.createBufferSource()`. Did you mean to say that "audioContext holds the file that has been loaded"? If so, it looks like you're doing what I'd expect. What behavior are you seeing, and what are you expecting?

Comment: @Palpatim Hi Palpatim, thanks for your comment, well I'm actually getting what I want, check out my Edit section in my question and check out the full code on jsfiddle and check out the live demo too. That's what I currently have working. I just need to implement pause and play buttons in any way possible, I'm expecting a simple way to put buttons on this code, that's it. After looking and going through the entire code, would you be able to let me know if anything pops in your head please?

Comment: @Palpatim so I'm expecting somewhere on the lines of gettings these to work and implemented proper way **function playAudio(){
    document.getElementById("audio").play();
    }**   **<button type="button" onClick="playAudio()"> Play</button>**  Same goes for pause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a scoping issue. From the [MDN entry about variable declarations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var):

> The scope of a variable declared with `var` is its current execution context, which is either the enclosing function or, for variables declared outside any function, global.
>
> Assigning a value to an undeclared variable implicitly creates it as a global variable (it becomes a property of the global object) when the assignment is executed.

As you are declaring the variable like `var audioBufferSourceNode = ...`, then you are making it a local variable to the `_visualize` method, and that's the reason why you cannot access it from *out of the library*.

What you can do:

1. Remove the `var` keyword for that variable declaration:

   ```
   audioBufferSourceNode = audioContext.createBufferSource()
   ```
2. Declare the variable globally (according to the explanation above, this step would be optional as the variable will implicitly be created as a global variable).

With this, you would be making `audioBufferSourceNode` a global variable and that implies certain risks (e.g.: there could be conflicts with other variables, it could be manipulated by any other methods, it is more difficult to maintain and debug if there are errors).

You should consider [@Palpatim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31003413/how-do-i-implement-play-pause-buttons-on-an-audiosourcenode-in-javascript/31006292?noredirect=1#comment50080348_31006292)'s suggestion below, keep the variable encapsulated in the module, and create an accessor so you can get and manipulate it from outside the module itself.

Comment: Okay once I remove the   var  keyword for that variable, what would I need to do now to implement a stop and pause button?
Please check out the edit section on my question at the bottom. It has the full code and working demo too.

Comment: It would be better design to keep the variable encapsulated within the scope of your module, and add an explicit accessor, as in `getAudioBufferSourceNode()`. Unnecessarily adding members to the global namespace is dangerous at worst, and a sloppy coding practice at best.

Comment: @Palpatim Okay, could you provide a working code as the solution to this question, so that I can mark it as answered please? specifically a working play and pause button so I can test it? Thank you

Comment: @Hedi The library snippet you posted is appropriate for troubleshooting your root issue: "I need a reference to the audioBufferSourceNode so I can implement a play/pause button". However, a full implementation would involve refactoring the audioBufferSourceNode instantiation into a separate method and then coding your accessor. Even @alvaro-montoro's answer, for example, assumes that you will always call `_visualize` before attempting to play/pause the audio. If this is your own library, you should have enough to go on. If this is a third-party library, you should contact the maintainers.

Comment: @Palpatim, you are correct. I edited the answer to reflect the risks of having a global variable and added the suggestion of having an accessor to manipulate the variable